# The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret)

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, lampp

I can resolve this blowfish_secret error on my phpmyadmin. I already added on /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php a 32-character random phrase, like bellow

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '@PB!rQ9gf68IeNLEVIW#ro*$At=$HasX';
```

And restarted the apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But the error is still there. Does anyone know how to solve? I use Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why your example didn't work, but you might try a hex char string instead of what you have.  In my case I'm using an automated setup BASH script that first installs phpMyAdmin, copies `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`, and then does this:

```
export SECRET=`php -r "echo bin2hex(random_bytes(16));"`
echo "\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$SECRET';" >> config.inc.php
```

The resulting value of `$SECRET` looks something like this:

```
8acb120e574d5b679c9d9300955e744e
```

The last line of `config.inc.php` looks like this:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '8acb120e574d5b679c9d9300955e744e';
```

Comment: Thank's, this solution works for me, before I used : openssl rand -base64 32 and I copied the result to config.inc.php, but still have the error

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned php version so assuming that you are on version 7.x
if so, then $cfg['blowfish_secret'] entry need to be of certain length (max is 46 char), sometime this issue is caused by length of blowfish_secret passphrase in config, especially when it is shorter, just try to increase it to 45 or 46 characters.